# Is a URL with querystring SEO friendly?

Tags: seo, url, query-string

I have developed a CMS that works with ID in urls.

```
http://example.com/content/?id=10
```

My customers asked me to add keywords in URLs to be seo firendly. I am not sure if there is a certain definition for a seo friendly URL? Are the following syntax seo friendly? In other word does it matter how a keyword should appear in URL to be seo friendly?

```
http://example.com/content/?id=10#test
http://example.com/content/?id=10&keyword=test
```

Comment: Keywords in URLs have little direct search engine ranking benefit.  See  [Are keywords in URLs good SEO or needlessly redundant?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/are-keywords-in-urls-good-seo-or-needlessly-redundant).  Keywords in URLs help users know what they are clicking on, especially when the link is shared just as a URL.  Using keywords in the URL can slightly increase the click through rate from search engine result pages.

Comment: Search engines don't care much about your URL structure as long as you are consistent.   Using "SEO friendly" URLs helps you be consistent.  `?id=10`, `?id=10&keyword=test`, and `?keyword=test&id=10` are all different URLs to search engines.   If you go with that, you need to make sure that search engines only ever see one of those.  That means linking on your site to exactly the same URL every time, and using redirects or canonical tags for cases in which an alternate URL accidentally leaks.

Comment: Users also like simple URLs.   It helps usability when you remove punctuation and other extraneous details from your URLs.  `http://example.com/test` is much easier to read, remember, and type, than anything you have proposed.  Adding an ID is very common to work seamlessly with a database.  When using an ID in the URL, you should pay attention to where it appears in the URL for SEO and usability.  See [What is the best placement for the ID in a URL for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16641/what-is-the-best-placement-for-the-id-in-a-url-for-seo)

Answer (score 2):

While search engines can recognise these kinds of URL, I can't see them being considered search engine  friendly as anything after the ? would be considered a key or value.

Its fairly standard now to use address rewriting to represent URLs containing strings as URLs with an artificial path (WordPress calls these permalinks). This is typically done in the webserver sifteare using Rewrite Rules.